# Retrofit+Dagger2 (retrofit null pointer)

Tags: android, dagger2, moxy

У меня в приложении реализовано Moxy(Model+Presenter+View)

Вылетает Null Pointer во время получения api из retrofit.

Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class,AppModule.class})
public interface RetrofitComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
    void inject(App app);
}
```

RetrofitModule:

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
    private String url;

    public RetrofitModule(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Gson provideGson(){
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

App:

```
public class App extends Application {
    RetrofitComponent retrofitComponent;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        retrofitComponent= DaggerRetrofitComponent.builder()
                .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule(Constants.BASE_URL))
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public RetrofitComponent getRetrofitComponent() {
        return retrofitComponent;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
 @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    RetrofitComponent retrofitComponent;
    public Model(GetDataRetrofit getDataRetrofit) {

        this.getDataRetrofit = getDataRetrofit;
    }

    public void retrofitCall() {
/*        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() 
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();*/
//        RetrofitComponent retrofitComponent=retrofit.create(RetrofitComponent.class);
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);//ЗДЕСЬ ВЫЛЕТАЕТ NPE
        getDataRetrofit.getBody(api.listData(), true);
        Log.i("GetBodyPresent", "1");
    }
```

Что делаю не так?Где ошибка?

Comment: Кажется, вы забыли заинжектить ретрофит в модель. Т.е. типа такого вызвать в кострукторе `Model ` - `App.getinstance(). getRetrofitComponent().inject(this)`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб когда я пишу эту фразу в конструкторе, он не находит метод getInstance, вообще не одного геттера нет

Comment: Этот геттер и метод inject надо создать. Геттер должен возвращать экземпляр приложения из статической переменной. Сам геттер тоже статический должен быть. Т.е. вам нужен синглтон `App` класса

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было сделать геттер в Application static, и после вызывать этот геттер в том классе, в котором ты хочешь использовать Inject

```
App.getRetrofitComponent.inject(this)
```